# Aid debugging a simple javascript project

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete this project in my college Javascript course.
As far as I can see my logic is sound but I am not doing something correctly and am not able to figure out what is wrong?..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
    function monthAsString(num){
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
         "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        return months[num-1];
    }






    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Textfield to Textfield</title>
    <script src="DateUDFs.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*
            Write a function called getMonth() that passes the
            month number entered by the user to the monthAsString()
            function in DateUDFs.js and writes the result in
            the monthName field.
        */

    function getMonth() {

    var elementMonthNumber = document.getElementById('monthNumber');
    var elementMonthName = document.getElementById('monthName');

    var month = monthAsString(elementMonthNumber.value);

    elementMonthName.value = month;




    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('getmonthbutton').addEventListener('click', getMonth , false);
        }
    }

     // pseudo code
    // When the document loads grab the button and add a click event listener,
    //on click call the get month function.

    // In the get month function.
    //
    // Grab the input field then grab the output field.
    // Pass the value of the input field to the monthAsString function.
    // Set the value of the output field to be = to the string value of the input value.


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Month Check</h1>
    <form name="dateForm">
        Month Number: <input type="text" name="monthNumber" id="monthNumber" size="2">
        <input type="button" value="Get Month" id="getmonthbutton"><br>
        Month Name: <input type="text" name="monthName" id="monthName" size="10">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Did you try debugging?

Comment: It is supposed to output the string value of the array in the monthAsString function. Based on the index value of the number inputted by the user. But I can not get it to work. I tried using console.log but it is not returning anything. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What does "can not get it to work" mean? What is happening, compared to what you expect to happen? "Doesn't work" is not a description of a problem.  Try opening your browser's development tools and putting a breakpoint on `var elementMonthNumber = ` in your `getMonth()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can get the month number.
You were adding javascript code out of the script tag which is not correct.

```js
function monthAsString(num){
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
     "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    return months[num-1];
    }

    

    window.onload = function() {
        const elementMonthNumber = document.getElementById('monthNumber');
        const elementMonthName = document.getElementById('monthName');
        document.getElementById('getmonthbutton').addEventListener('click', getMonth);

        function getMonth() {
        let monthNumber = elementMonthNumber.value;
        console.log(monthNumber); //the monthNumber is displayed
        //now try to display the month name since it's a homework 
        //and if you get stuck just comment
    }
    }
```

```html
<h1>Month Check</h1>
<form name="dateForm">
    Month Number: <input type="text" name="monthNumber" id="monthNumber" size="2">
    <input type="button" value="Get Month" id="getmonthbutton"><br>
    Month Name: <input type="text" name="monthName" id="monthName" size="10">
</form>
```